# Where can I get blank SVG maps of countries and states?

Tags: svg, maps

Where can I get SVG blank maps of countries along with their states?

I saw United States here, but I couldn't find other countries (Asia especially)
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg

Comment: I am not sure if this is on topic at http://gis.stackexchange.com/, but it probably is at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  and definiely at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[d-maps.com](http://d-maps.com/) offers free maps in many formats including svg, you might find what you're looking for there.

Comment: Maps outline not accurate. :(

Comment: These files look hm... strange...at first glimse... Wiki*m*edia does the job for me...

Answer (score 45):

amCharts has a lot of free svg maps of most countries of the world, also an API for making these maps interactive: http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/

Disclaimer: I am the author of amCharts.

Comment: This is fantastic, it has better maps for interaction than any of the other answers! Great work.

Comment: I think I am in love with you. That site is amazing! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Alas, not all world countries are included in there. I couldn't find Lebanon (my country), Jordan, etc.

Comment: Don't bother, Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0

Comment: This should be selected as the best answer

Comment: BTW, we we also created a tool which allows creating pixelated SVG maps, manipulating them - adding lines, images etc: http://pixelmap.amcharts.com/

Answer (score 12):

Try the [Wikipedia blank maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBlank_maps#Asia). Some of them have regional boundaries (such as Thailand). The Wikipedia maps are auto-generated from tools like Inkscape so I recommend cleaning them up with [Scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/) before you use them

Comment: I saw that, but they only have maps for very few countries

Comment: See also a similar resource on Wikimedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Blank_SVG_maps_of_the_world

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/djaiss/mapsicon has a good collection of svg and png shapes of every country.

Comment: "Thanks so much for the suggestions everybody. I'm glad you like this project. However, I won't update anymore this repository. I'll let it as is from now on, for the community. For that matter, I've disabled the Issues. I hope you understand."  From 2 years ago. This isn't being maintained at all

Comment: Despite that, there won't be much change for most coutries. It's certainly wrth a look. But, that said, nothign beats http://D-maps.com , as Erik said

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend seeking out a utility that converts shapefiles (the GIS mapping standard) to SVG paths, etc.  Here is one I found that looks alright, though I haven't tested it:

[shp2svg](http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/utils/shp2svg/)

And you can find shapefiles on [data.gov](http://www.data.gov) or other government websites.

A good shapefile set is the TIGER shapefile, a bunch of layers created by the U.S. Census

Answer (score 0):

Here are some maps of countries in vector format:
http://www.your-vector-maps.com/countries/
They are .eps though and some are not free :(

I'm also looking for svg maps but just the border in outline, for each country.